# How do I use infopath to host a form on a parent website and have the sharepoint list on the child site

Tags: 2010, infopath, permissions, custom-list, custom-form

I have a client with a parent website that is open to their IT department with a child website that's permissions are set to just their members of the team. A public parent site and a private child site. How do I put a form on the parent site that's connected to a list in the private child site?

The goal is to have a submission box that everyone in IT can submit to but only members of the few members of the smaller team be able to read/edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This will be easier if the restricted list is not in a sub site, but in the main site.

Break permission inheritance for the list and give the list its own, unique settings.

Give everybody "Contribute" permissions to the list. In Advanced Settings select that users can only see the item they created themselves.

Give the IT folks permissions to manage the list, so they can see all items.

Now the regular user can only see the list items they created. They wrote the text, so there's no harm in them reading it again. They won't see anyone else's submissions.  You can clamp it down even further if you create a new permission level (copy the Contribute) and remove the "delete" option, so the regular user cannot delete even their own submissions.

If you don't allow the regular user to access All Site Contents, they will never know how to get to the list in the first place.